# networkx read_dot() is not reading subgraph edges

Tags: python, networkx, dot

I have a dot that contains multiple clusters. When I call networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.read_dot(file) the result does not contain any edges in the clusters. It reads all other edges and nodes except whatever is in the subgraph cluster.

this is my dot file:

```
Digraph G {
    splines=spline;
//DHLS version: 0.1.1" [shape = "none" pos = "20,20!"]
        "brCst_block1" [type = "Constant", bbID= 1, in = "in1:1", out = "out1:1", value = "0x1"];
        "cst_0" [type = "Constant", bbID= 1, in = "in1:1", out = "out1:1", value = "0x00000000"];
        "phi_1" [type = "Mux", bbID= 2, in = "in1?:1 in2:32 in3:32 ", out = "out1:32", delay=0.366];
        "cst_1" [type = "Constant", bbID= 1, in = "in1:1", out = "out1:1", value = "0x00000000"];
        "phi_2" [type = "Mux", bbID= 2, in = "in1?:1 in2:10 in3:10 ", out = "out1:10", delay=0.366];
        "load_5" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "mc_load_op", bbID= 2, portId= 0, in = "in1:32 in2:10 ", out = "out1:32 out2:10 ", delay=0.000, latency=2, II=1];
        "cst_2" [type = "Constant", bbID= 2, in = "in1:10", out = "out1:10", value = "0x000003E7"];
        "sub_6" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "sub_op", in = "in1:32 in2:32 ", out = "out1:32 ", delay=1.693, latency=0, II=1];
        "load_9" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "mc_load_op", bbID= 2, portId= 0, in = "in1:32 in2:32 ", out = "out1:32 out2:32 ", delay=0.000, latency=2, II=1];
        "mul_10" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "mul_op", in = "in1:32 in2:32 ", out = "out1:32 ", delay=0.000, latency=4, II=1];
        "add_11" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "add_op", in = "in1:32 in2:32 ", out = "out1:32 ", delay=1.693, latency=0, II=1];
        "cst_3" [type = "Constant", bbID= 2, in = "in1:1", out = "out1:1", value = "0x00000001"];
        "add_12" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "add_op", in = "in1:10 in2:10 ", out = "out1:10 ", delay=1.693, latency=0, II=1];
        "cst_4" [type = "Constant", bbID= 2, in = "in1:10", out = "out1:10", value = "0x000003E8"];
        "icmp_13" [type = "Operator", bbID= 2, op = "icmp_ult_op", in = "in1:10 in2:10 ", out = "out1:1 ", delay=1.530, latency=0, II=1];
        "ret_0" [type = "Operator", bbID= 3, op = "ret_op", in = "in1:32 ", out = "out1:32 ", delay=0.000, latency=0, II=1];
        "phi_n0" [type = "Merge", bbID= 3, in = "in1:32 ", out = "out1:32", delay=0.000];
        "fork_0" [type = "Fork", bbID= 2, in = "in1:10", out = "out1:10 out2:10 out3:10 "];
    subgraph cluster_0 {
    color = "darkgreen";
        label = "block1";
        "brCst_block1" -> "fork_3" [color = "magenta", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "cst_0" -> "branch_0" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "cst_1" -> "branch_1" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "fork_3" -> "branch_1" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in2"];
        "fork_3" -> "branch_0" [color = "red", from = "out2", to = "in2"];
        "fork_3" -> "branchC_4" [color = "gold3", from = "out3", to = "in2"];
        "start_0" -> "forkC_6" [color = "gold3", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "forkC_6" -> "cst_0" [color = "gold3", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "forkC_6" -> "cst_1" [color = "gold3", from = "out2", to = "in1"];
        "forkC_6" -> "branchC_4" [color = "gold3", from = "out3", to = "in1"];
        "forkC_6" -> "brCst_block1" [color = "gold3", from = "out4", to = "in1"];
    }
        "branch_0" -> "phi_1" [color = "blue", minlen = 3, from = "out1", to = "in2"];
        "branch_0" -> "sink_1" [color = "blue", minlen = 3, from = "out2", to = "in1"];
        "branch_1" -> "phi_2" [color = "blue", minlen = 3, from = "out1", to = "in2"];
        "branch_1" -> "sink_2" [color = "blue", minlen = 3, from = "out2", to = "in1"];
        "branchC_4" -> "phiC_1" [color = "gold3", minlen = 3, from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "branchC_4" -> "sink_4" [color = "gold3", minlen = 3, from = "out2", to = "in1"];
    subgraph cluster_1 {
    color = "darkgreen";
        label = "block2";
        "fork_4" -> "branchC_5" [color = "gold3", from = "out3", to = "in2"];
        "phiC_1" -> "fork_9" [color = "green", from = "out2", to = "in1"];
        "phiC_1" -> "branchC_5" [color = "gold3", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "source_0" -> "cst_2" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "source_1" -> "cst_3" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "source_2" -> "cst_4" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "fork_9" -> "phi_1" [color = "red", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
        "fork_9" -> "phi_2" [color = "red", from = "out2", to = "in1"];
    }
        "branch_2" -> "phi_1" [color = "blue", minlen = 3, from = "out1", to = "in3"];
        "branchC_5" -> "phiC_1" [color = "gold3", minlen = 3, from = "out1", to = "in2"];
        "branchC_5" -> "phiC_2" [color = "gold3", minlen = 3, from = "out2", to = "in1"];
    subgraph cluster_2 {
    color = "darkgreen";
        label = "block3";
        "phiC_2" -> "sink_0" [color = "gold3", from = "out1", to = "in1"];
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[image: this is the result]

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this problem myself. The problem is in https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pydot.html#from_pydot.

The pydot data structure is hierarchical, but from_pydot assumes it is flat. You need to write a recursive version of from_pydot that goes down the py_dot data structure doing basically the same thing as the existing version. You can use P.get_subgraph_list() to get the subgraphs of the current graph. So the structure of your code will look like:

```
def new_from_pydot( P , N ):
  # do what from_pydot current does to P
  for s in P.get_subgraph_list():
    new_from_pydot( s , N )
```